# Django Rest Framework does not show the proper error when submitting in Postman

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have the following codes:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def selected_device(request,pk=None):
    if pk != None:        
        try:
            devices = Device.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        except Device.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        try:
            devicedetail = DeviceDetail.objects.filter(DD2DKEY=pk)
        except DeviceDetail.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)        
        devserializer = DeviceSerializers(devices, many=True)
        devdserializer = DeviceDetailSerializers(devicedetail, many=True)        
        results = {
            "device":devserializer.data,
            "device_details" : devdserializer.data,       
        }
        return Response(results)
```

As stated in the code, there is try and except to try to get the data. When i set `pk=210`, this data does not exist in the table. It does not display the status of 400. Instead it display [] with nothing inside in postman. How can i fix this?
[image]

Comment: `filter` does not raise `DoesNotExist`. Did you mean to use `get`? So `Device.objects.get(pk=pk)`

Comment: It worked but I needed to use ```filter```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `exists()` method as,

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def selected_device(request, pk=None):
    if not pk:
        return Response({"detail": "'pk' is empty"}, status=400)
    
    devices = Device.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    devicedetail = DeviceDetail.objects.filter(DD2DKEY=pk)
    if devices.exists() and devicedetail.exists():
        devserializer = DeviceSerializers(devices, many=True)
        devdserializer = DeviceDetailSerializers(devicedetail, many=True)
        results = {
            "device": devserializer.data,
            "device_details": devdserializer.data,
        }
        return Response(results)
    
    return Response(status=400)
```

Comment: Thanks ! This was the answer I needed as I need to use ```.filter```